# In HTML5, a <div> is technically a block-level element, but behaves as an in-line element. Is this a special 'hybrid' element?

Tags: html, inline, block

A block level element as defined by the W3Schools has having a line break before and after the element, such as *p, h1,* etc. Non nested inline elements either start on their own line (no line break) or remain on the same line if nested.

While *span* behaves normally (as well as all other inline elements). *Div* never creates line breaks like block elements all do, but only starts on a new line at the opening of the div element.

Perhaps I'm missing something since everyone talks about *DIV* being block level, but it behaves like an inline element in that it starts a new line if not nested, doesn't create line breaks, but acts like something else entirely that when a *div* is nested with another *div* it just creates a new line.

Is *DIV* the only "hybrid" element like this? Am I missing something more fundamental?

Comment: No element adds a linebreak anywhere ever (`br` (kinda) does :) ).

Comment: Most block-level elements have a default `margin` in the user agent CSS, while `div` doesn't. I suspect this is what you're seeing.

Comment: To follow on from @PeeHaa's comment, see http://w3fools.com for details.

Comment: As an alternative resource may I suggest: https://developer.mozilla.org so you can vanish w3schools from your search engine result to never look back :)

Comment: Or even better look at the official spec: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html

Comment: The W3C is the 'official' site, but I think it needs to have a redesign, and have the pages split into smaller sizes.

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff You mean like this: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/spec.html?

Comment: @PeeHaa Yes, I mean that. Pages of a Table of Contents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No elements create line breaks. You're merely seeing the effects of different default styles, which have different `margin` and `padding` values. The default styles vary per browser, but often look something like the [very dated] reference stylesheet included with the HTML 4 spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html

Comment: `<p>` has `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`.

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff as do others, wrote that too specifically :P

Comment: Is the Mozilla Developer Network as bad as W3Schools? MDN (as Shaquin cites below) says the block level starts on new lines, PeeHaw (as stated above) thinks that no element adds breaks anywhere, and you state that it's not a line break, but default padding that creates the 'illusion' of padding but this can't be the case since if I put a border around the DIV it encases 1 line of text only - if it was from margin/padding, then the border would be around the margin and it's not. I guess there's still some confusion.

Comment: MDN is great for JavaScript, I don't know about their HTML reference since I generally refer to the HTML5 spec.

Comment: MDN is a great and accurate reference all round. It's not a great place to learn though.

Answer (score 2):

The [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org), or MDN, is the best place to learn about HTML.

There is an explanation of `<div>` here: **[div | Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/div)**:

> The Document Division (`<div>`) HTML element is ***generic container for flow content, which does not inherently represent anything***.
>   It can be used to group elements for styling purposes (using the class or id attributes), or because they share attribute values, such as lang.
>   It should be used only when no other semantic element (such as `<article>` or `<nav>`) is appropriate.

Here is the comparison between **block-level** and **inline** elements:

---

**[Block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements):**

---

> The differences between inline and block-level elements are:
>
> **Formatting**
>
> By default, block-level elements begin on new lines.
>
> **Content model**
>
> Generally, block-level elements may contain inline elements and other block-level elements.
>   Inherent in this structural distinction is the idea that block elements create "larger" structures than inline elements.

---

**[Inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Inline_elements):**

---

> Differences between inline and block-level elements:
>
> **Content model**
>
> Generally, inline elements may contain only data and other inline elements.
>
> **Formatting**
>
> By default, inline elements do not begin with new line.